# Python beginner question for basic scripting

Tags: python-3.x, scripting

I am going through Python Complete reference book, and in the exercise there is one problem which says to add the following:

```
    L=[1, 2]
    L.append(L)
    print (L)
```

In response I get an output like this

```
    [1, 2, 3, [...]]
```

However in the book it mentions that until you hit the break key it will be infinitely appending the list: as follows:
an unending stream of [1, 2, [1, 2, [1, 2, [1, 2, and so on, until you hit the
break-key combination

Can somebody please explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I think it depends with the compiler in my case it showed [1,2, [...]]
However I think the mean of the "..." is that you are recursively appending list on it

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

The program isn't actually infinitely *appending* the list (that would imply that the list length is equal to infinity, which it's not --- if you run len(L), you will see that the length is 3). Rather, it is infinitely *recursing*.

The list starts out with two elements, 1 and 2 (I take it you have a mistake in your output above where you show "3" being printed, since there is never a 3 added to the list).

You then tell the list you want the third element to be equal to the existing list. However, due to how python passes data, what you're essentially doing is storing a reference to list L. Something like this: [1, 2, ref(L)].

When you go to print the list then, the first two elements appear easily: 1, 2.
However, for the third element, python says "let me go grab list L and show it." Okay, so what is list L? It is [1, 2, ref(L)]. Hm. So python says again, "okay, this third element is kind of tricky. I know it is a list of length 3, and I know what the first two elements are, but I need to go get the third element, which is list L. What is list L? ..." and on it goes.

The [...] is to indicate that the third element (L[2]) is never able to be fully defined because each ref(L) that is fetched contains within it another ref(L) element.

Thus your actual output is something like this:

```
=> [1, 2, ref(L)]
=> [1, 2, [1, 2, ref(L)]]
=> [1, 2, [1, 2, [1, 2, ref(L)]]]
=> [1, 2, [1, 2, [1, 2, [1, 2, ref(L)]]]]
...
```

which python helpfully truncates as [1, 2, [...]] to show that this pattern just repeats forever.